# Why does the console.writeline throws error on printing a state? Am I implementing the state machine correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, action, state-machine

I am just new to state machines and tried my hands on the process of Submit, Review and Approved scenario using state machines. It throws error on     `fsm.ProcessEvent(FiniteStateMachine.Events.Reviewed);`

i.e. object reference null exception. I cannot figure out? Am I implementing the scenario correctly?

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var fsm = new FiniteStateMachine();
            Console.WriteLine(fsm.State);
            fsm.ProcessEvent(FiniteStateMachine.Events.Submitted);
            Console.WriteLine(fsm.State);
            fsm.ProcessEvent(FiniteStateMachine.Events.Reviewed);
            Console.WriteLine(fsm.State);
            fsm.ProcessEvent(FiniteStateMachine.Events.Approved);
            Console.WriteLine(fsm.State);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        class FiniteStateMachine
        {
            public enum States { Submitted, Reviewed, Approved};
            public States State { get; set; }

            public enum Events { Submitted, Reviewed, Approved};

            private Action[,] fsm;

            public FiniteStateMachine()
            {
                this.fsm = new Action[3, 3] { 
                //Submitted,    Reviewed,               TurnOff,           
                {this.SubmittedForReview,   null,                   null               },     //Submitted
                {null,          this.Reviewing,          null              },     //Reviewed
                {null,          null,                   this.Approving} };       //Approved
            }

            public void ProcessEvent(Events theEvent)
            {
                this.fsm[(int)this.State, (int)theEvent].Invoke();
            }

            private void SubmittedForReview() { this.State = States.Submitted; }
            private void Reviewing() { this.State = States.Reviewed; }
            private void Approving() { this.State = States.Approved; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your FSM. You're creating a multidimensional array of actions. Instead try a look up, like a dictionary. Here you have a dictionary where the key is the status and the value is the action you want to take. This worked for me. Here's what I changed.

```
    private Dictionary<int, Action> fsm;

    public FiniteStateMachine()
    {
        this.fsm = new Dictionary<int, Action>() {
        { (int)States.Submitted, SubmittedForReview },
            {(int)States.Reviewed, Reviewing },
            {(int)States.Approved, Approving}
            };
    }

    public void ProcessEvent(Events theEvent)
    {
        var action = fsm[(int)theEvent];
        action.Invoke();
    }
```

**EDIT 1**

The reason you're getting a null reference when processing Reviewed is because the State is set to Submitted. Enums in C# start at 0 so when you call

```
 fsm.ProcessEvent(FiniteStateMachine.Events.Reviewed);
```

what are you trying to look up is

```
 public void ProcessEvent(Events theEvent)
    {
        //this.fsm[(int)this.State, (int)theEvent].Invoke();
        this.fsm[0, 1].Invoke();
    }
```

because this.State is still Submitted. So you are trying to Invoke the action at index 1 of the index 0 which is null. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

in your case it's normal to have an **object reference null exception**  because you haven't an event for **Reviewed** for state **Submitted**  you need to arrange your array.

you can use the code below to avoid **object reference null exception** (feature of c# 6)

```
    public void ProcessEvent(Events theEvent)
    {
        this.fsm[(int)this.State, (int)theEvent]?.Invoke();
    }
```